# ASP.net invalid view state on back button

Tags: asp.net, caching, browser, viewstate, back

On the production server my ASP.net site is running, I have been running into an invalid view state error - "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."

This occurs when a user navigates away from the main page via a html link, then clicks the back button of their browser and finally tries to cause a callback or postback e.g.via tabs on a gridview which causes a callback.

I think it might have something to do with the back button causing a cached page to be returned which then invalidates viewstate as it remembers the view state from the page instead of regenerating it? But im not sure if my logic is correct.

Any ideas why this is happening, am i right in assuming it's something to do with the back button causing a cached version of the page, even though i haven't explicitly told my pages to be cached?